# Rails/Heroku Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

I was trying to deploy my app on Heroku using git. It runs successfully on my system. The app was successfully deployed but shows Application ERROR on checking if it works.
I tried searching for a similar error but I could not find anything specific to my problem. The Heroku logs is given below:

```
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
app[web.1]:     from bin/rails:9:in `require'
app[web.1]:     from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
heroku[run.2807]: Process exited with status 0
heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
heroku[run.2807]: State changed from up to complete
heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 57671 -e production`
app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
app[web.1]: => Rails 5.0.5 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:57671
app[web.1]: Exiting
app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require': No such file to load -- carrierwave (LoadError)
app[web.1]:     from /app/app/uploaders/ckeditor_attachment_file_uploader.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:380:in `block in require_or_load'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `block in load_interlock'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:12:in `block in loading'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:150:in `exclusive'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:11:in `loading'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `load_interlock'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:358:in `require_or_load'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:511:in `load_missing_constant'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:203:in `const_missing'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:543:in `load_missing_constant'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:203:in `const_missing'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:543:in `load_missing_constant'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:203:in `const_missing'
app[web.1]:     from /app/app/models/ckeditor/attachment_file.rb:2:in `<class:AttachmentFile>'
app[web.1]:     from /app/app/models/ckeditor/attachment_file.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:380:in `block in require_or_load'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `block in load_interlock'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:12:in `block in loading'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:150:in `exclusive'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:11:in `loading'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `load_interlock'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:358:in `require_or_load'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:336:in `depend_on'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:252:in `require_dependency'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:476:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in `each'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in `block in eager_load!'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:473:in `each'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:473:in `eager_load!'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:354:in `eager_load!'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.5/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:59:in `each'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.5/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:59:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
app[web.1]:     from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
app[web.1]:     from /app/config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
app[web.1]:     from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
app[web.1]:     from /app/config.ru:in `new'
app[web.1]:     from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/server.rb:319:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/server.rb:219:in `app'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:84:in `app'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/server.rb:354:in `wrapped_app'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/server.rb:283:in `start'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:104:in `start'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:90:in `block in server'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
app[web.1]:     from bin/rails:9:in `require'
app[web.1]:     from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"
```

I have removed the date and time of the logs so its easier to read and the lines are not as wide.

Comment: Probably relevant to show `/app/app/uploaders/ckeditor_attachment_file_uploader.rb` since that seems to be where the error is.

Comment: Its saying it cant load carrierwave, is that in your Gemfile?

Comment: Link for [/app/app/uploaders/ckeditor_attachment_file_uploader.rb](https://pastebin.com/FikZL7bC)

Comment: carrierwave is not in my Gem file

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you have the gem `carrierwave` added to your Gemfile:

https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave

From their Github page:

> In Rails, add it to your Gemfile:
>
> ```
> gem 'carrierwave', '~> 1.0'
> ```

Comment: Added carrierwave. Now it shows `No such file to load -- mini_magick (LoadError)` in place of **carrierwave**

Comment: Follow that same process for all missing gems, here's mini_magick's github: https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick. `gem "mini_magick"` In fact im a little suprised you got this working at all before Heroku w/ out any of these in your Gemfile....

Comment: He probably had this gems installed and running the app without `bundle exec`

Comment: You shouldn't have to run bundle exec when starting rails.